# Remove all third-party drivers

Tags: windows, dell, drivers, dism

Is there a way to un-DISM all drivers from Windows?

Our images are injected with Dell's CAB driver packs, but with our new Optiplex 7020's we're getting a video error on bootup. We suspect there could be a conflict with the video drivers. We're also concerned that older drivers could be an issue, so we want to remove all old Dell CAB driver packs. Is this possible?

Comment: You may want to clarify, on what I assume is, about removing drivers from .WIM images. Add the imaging (or related) tags to your question would probably help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are asking whether or not you are able to remove drivers from a **DISM** (formerly ImageX for all you old folks!) created **.WIM image**. 
To answer your question quickly, the answer is: Yes!
To answer your question more verbosely, the answer is: Absolutely, yes!

The operation you are interested in performing is a two part process:
see the [official Microsoft instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825070.aspx) here:

**First**, you need to use DISM to **mount** the offline image. This is achieved by using the DISM command with the /mount-image switch: example

```
Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:C:\test\images\install.wim /Name:"Windows 7 Image" /MountDir:C:\test\offline
```

*Special notes: The /mountdir you declare is a FOLDER, install.wim is the name of the .wim file you are servicing.*

**Second** Use the /Remove-Driver switch: example

```
Dism /Image:C:\test\offline /Remove-Driver /Driver:DELL1.inf /Driver:DELL2.inf
```

*Here you are removing the drivers DELL1.inf and DELL2.inf, you need to know the name of the .inf file that you wish to remove and it is done individually. If these drivers were originally installed using an .exe, you can always un(7)Zip the .cab file and *Sometimes works* .exe file for the installer to find the names of the .inf files contained.*

**Don't forget** to /unmount-image and /commit

```
Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:C:\test\offline /Commit
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing drivers individually with DISM is a pain. You need to Get-Drivers and figure out what the system has named the original drivers. Then individually delete the ones you don't want, which could be hundreds and hundreds of entries. Try this: [https://brashear.me/blog/2014/07/30/remove-all-drivers-from-a-windows-image-by-a-certain-vendor/](http://web.archive.org/web/20141112144948)

Using Powershell he was able to remove all drivers from a specific vendor. i.e. Intel, AMD, Ati, etc... It's not exactly what you want, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the only thing out there... something called the dell 'de-crapifyer' but maybe it might help.

Info page:

```
http://yorkspace.wordpress.com/2006/04/10/introducing-the-dell-de-crapifier/
```

...which now sends you to:

```
http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/
```

It is not apparently a free tool but I believe it was at one time.

Anyway, I hope this helps.